# Update values that have something in common

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join

I´m trying to set a value for those pets who share a owner.

```
update Pets
set multiple = 1
where Phone_owner in (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT Phone_owner, COUNT(*) Total
        FROM Pets
        GROUP BY Phone_owner
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) a
    );
```

I get this error:

> Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: `(SELECT * FROM(` --> `(SELECT Phone_owner FROM(`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `JOIN` rather than `WHERE ... IN`

```
UPDATE Pets AS p1
JOIN (
    SELECT Phone_owner
    FROM Pets
    GROUP BY Phone_owner
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS p2 ON p1.Phone_owner = p2.Phone_owner
SET p1.multiple = 1
```